# Show values in bar graphs in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a chart using some values in python-matplot lib, But i wanted to show values inside the bars, I tried something, Now i'm able to get values, That is not inside the bars, Its position is not correct. Can anyone help me out of this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tick_label = ['Impacted Lines', 'Added/Edited', 'Table type change', 'Deleted']

def addlabels(x,y):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.text(i, y[i]//2,y[i], ha = 'center',bbox = dict(facecolor = 'white', alpha = .5))

x_axis=[1,2,3,4]
y_axis=[3, 2, 6, 1]
plt.bar(x_axis, y_axis,tick_label = tick_label,width = 0.8, color = ['orange', 'green','blue','red'])
plt.ylim(0, len(output))

addlabels(x_axis,y_axis)
        
plt.ylabel('Total counts')
plt.title('Report Chart')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[Please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRAju.png)

Comment: Can you post your code ? You should be able to define the position of your text according to the axes referential.

Comment: Please always add code as text, never as image.  You can use `for xi, yi in zip(x, y):` instead of `for i in range(len(x))` because the list is numerical. And then `plt.text(xi, yi/2, yi, ha='center', va='center', ...)`.

Comment: yeah added code

Comment: Yes, Now the issue got fixed, Thank you so much @JohanC